# Discover nothing when using Bluetooth Low Energy on Samsung devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile

I follow [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) guide, and try to test **discovery feature** on *Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and Samsung Galaxy S3*.

But they can not find together via my application.

Therefore, I try to download **[nRF Utility](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordic.nordicbleapp)** from market place.

But it shows notification :

> Device not supported

While in market place, it said that :

> Note: Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Note 2 and Samsung Note 10.1 are currently supported handsets.

I think it gets the same issues.

I have no idea.

Anyone know this issue?

*p/s : It will run good on Google Nexus 4, 5, 7?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the note you wrote, it doesn't seem like the Note 3 is supported (it probably searches for specific models). You can see supported devices and sources here:
http://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/nRFready-Demo-APPS

There's a different nRF Utility for Nexus devices, as they use a different driver.
The samsung BLE drivers are for Android 4.2.2, while nexus devices run 4.3 and use the Google BLE API.
I haven't tested the Samsung BLE drivers myself, but from my experience, the Google API is not very stable, even on 4.4.
You might have to make some changes to your code if it's based on the Samsung drivers and you want to try the Nexus devices.